# Calculate Efficiency Loss of a Leak in a Hydraulic Cylinder

Tags: hydraulics, energy-efficiency

I am trying to figure out what the efficiency loss of a leaking hydraulic cylinder is.  This [master's thesis](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjm5pPi3YLgAhUQCKwKHfM1BX8QFjAAegQICRAC&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.mate.tue.nl%2Fmate%2Fpdfs%2F10299.pdf&usg=AOvVaw0UI7OlgfDT9rIm3kF0_Dc8) found that a controllable pitch propeller (essentially a hydraulic cylinder inside a rotating shaft to control the pitch of the propeller) had external leakage of  0.5 ltr/min at 40 bar and internal leakage of 3 ltr/min at 100 bar.  I was wondering if it would be possible to convert these numbers into a rough efficiency loss?

I have been google searching for days to try to find a reference to indicate how to make this calculation.  I also went all out and went to a local university library to use Engineering Village -- hoping to find some paper that did an analogous study but couldn't find much to help.

This seems relevant but not sure how to use it: [Losses through holes drilled in a pipe](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/19228/losses-through-holes-drilled-in-a-pipe)

Comment: What would you base the efficiency on? engine power input? Air or fluid moved? Blade Positioning error? Peak hydraulic fluid flow?

Comment: Engine power input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The efficiency is a dimensionless quantity and is calculated by power output devided by power input.

I hope you have the value of your power input? But you can also calculate it with the following formula. The left one is for your (electro-)motor which is convertible in your hydraulic pump.

$P_{mechanical}=M[Nm]*2*n[1/sec]*\pi=p[bar]*Q[l/min]=P_{hydraulic}$

There are three (main-)possibilities to get some energy loss in your system:

- the mechanical one caused by friction in your pump, motor, valves … - $P_{loss-mechanical} [W]$
- the pressure one caused by perfusion-resistance of the elements in your hydraulic system, e.g. in your piping – $P_{loss-\Delta p} [W]$
- the volumetric one caused by leakage in your hydraulic system – $P_{loss-volumetric} [W]$

The volumetric loss is your issue - mentioned by the two leakage (internal and external).

$P_{l- vol} [W]= \Sigma (p[bar]*Q[l/min])=10^5*40bar*1/60000*0,5l/min + 10^5*100bar*1/60000*3l/min=533,33 W$

Note the $10^5$ and the $1/60000$ are values because of the different units…

Now the equation for efficiency:

$n= P_{output}/P_{input}=(P_{input}-\Sigma(P_{loss}))/P_{input}=(P_{input}-P_{l- vol})/P_{input}=(P_{input}-533,33 W)/P_{input}$